# Binding selector 'salutation' did not match

Tags: angularjs

I'm having trouble testing a `binding` in an e2e test. Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<select ng-model="salutation" ng-options="s.value for s in salutations">
  <option value="">Please choose</option>
</select>
```

Controller:

```
function MainCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.salutations = [{
    key: "male",
    value: "Mr."
  }, {
    key: "female",
    value: "Mrs."
  }];  
  $scope.salutation = salutations[0];
}
```

E2E test:

```
...
describe('Form', function() {
  it('should initialize from model', function() {
    expect(binding('salutation')).toMatch('Mr.');
  }); 
});
...
```

When running the e2e test I get this error message:

```
select binding 'salutation'
Binding selector 'salutation' did not match.



<span>{{salutation}}</span>
```

Thx!

**UPDATE**: closed in favour of new question [Why doesn't binding() find a two-way-binding in an e2e test?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18630723/why-doesnt-binding-find-a-two-way-binding-in-an-e2e-test)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the page binding works since `salutations` is not in `$scope`, you need to change it to

```
function MainCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.salutations = [{
        key: "male",
        value: "Mr."
    }, {
        key: "female",
        value: "Mrs."
    }];
    $scope.salutation = $scope.salutations[0];
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately adding `salutations` to `$scope` didn't solve the problem. Anyway, thank you!