# Why doesn't binding() find a two-way-binding in an e2e test?

Tags: angularjs

The `binding()` function doesn't seem to find two-way-bindings in e2e tests. Assuming the following bindings:

```
<input ng-model="username">
<p>{{email}}</p>
<input ng-bind="password">
```

The following e2e test fails:

```
...
expect(binding('username')).toMatch('alice');
...
>> Binding selector 'username' did not match.
```

The following e2e tests succeeds:

```
...
expect(binding('email')).toMatch('alice@ab.com');
expect(binding('password')).toMatch('abc123');
...
```

Thx!

Answer (score 1):

Please try this way;

```
<input ng-model="username">
```

And in your E2E test;

```
expect(input('username').val()).toMatch('alice');
```

Comment: You're right, that would work. But I'm wondering why it isn't possible to inspect the binding directly.

Comment: Did you tried changing ng-model="username" to ng-bind ="username"

Comment: This makes the binding a "normal" binding. `ng-bind` is not a two-way-binding.